# How i can add new project to google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have an application that creates mobile applications.   I want to know is it possible to programmatically add each mobile app in the existing Google Analytics account for tracking?

Google analytic has API for getting report like following link(https://developers.google.com/analytics/)
but unfortunately I couldn't find proper document for adding new project to existing account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try again your question isn't clear.   Try and explain what you mean by "existing analytic with API"   What is it you wan to do with your mobile app? Display current google analytics data or log activity to google analytics?

Comment: I have built the application that could build the mobile app and I want to add that app to existing analytic account via  api.

Comment: Ok assuming I am  understanding your question correctly.   You have created an application that creates other mobile applications.   You want to  programmatically add each mobile app Google analytics for tracking?

Comment: Yes, exactly ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to programmatically add web properties to Google Analytics. It is part of the management API the method is called [Web Properties: insert](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/insert)

The first thing you need to know is that this method is in beta.  You need permission to use it.  If you want to use this I suggest you apply for beta now it can take a while (*Like a month*) to get access Google will email you if they allow you to join the beta.  The link to beta can be found at the top of this page in blue [Web Properties: insert](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/insert)

> Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete, patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources are currently available as a developer preview in limited beta. If you're interested in using these features,  request access to the beta.

The second thing you should know is that I am not sure it will allow you to create a mobile tracking account.   By what I can see in the documentation it only works with web analytics accounts which will not work for you since its a mobile application you want to track.

I think I have an account with access to this API I am going to check. I will let you know.  If its not supported then I guess we could create a feature request but it might take them a while to add it.